# Identify values not exist in two List with Java functional programming

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have two ArrayList of String with list of ID.

List list1 -> ["1", "2", "3," "4", "5", "6"]
and
List list2 -> ["2", "3," "4", "6"]

I want to get a list of ID not repeated.

List list3 -> ["1", "5"]

I've developed this with Java 7:

```
for (String id : list1) {
   if (!list2.contains(id)) {
     list3.add(id);
   }
 }
```

I want to do this in Java functional programming... is possible using streams or similar?

Comment: Why not just do `list1.removeAll(list2)` instead of loops or streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the correct (as in "more readable", "more idiomatic" and "less error-prone") way to do this is to use [`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)), as in

```
list1.removeAll(list2);
```

Note that this modifies the original list.

If you insist on using streams (or simply you don't want to modify the original list) you can filter out values that appear in both lists (i.e. letting only values from `list1` that are **not** contained in `list2` past the filter)

```
var list3 = list1.stream()
                 .filter(Predicate.not(list2::contains))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I used [`Predicate::not`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)) since you tagged the question with `java-11`. It's not available in Java 8. If you are stuck with Java 8 (or 9, or 10) the process is similar if a little more verbose

```
var list3 = list1.stream()
                 .filter(s -> !list2.contains(s))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```java
List<String> differences = listOne.stream()
            .filter(element -> !listTwo.contains(element))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-lists-difference